# Reshaping data.frame with a by-group where id variable repeats

Tags: r, group-by, reshape, transpose, data-wrangling

I want to reshape/ rearrange a dataset, that is stored as a data.frame with 2 columns:

- id (non-unique, i.e. can repeat over several rows) --> stored as character
- value --> stored as numeric value (range 1:3)

Sample data:

```
id <- as.character(1001:1003)
val_list <- data.frame(sample(1:3, size=12, replace=TRUE))
have <- data.frame(cbind(rep(id, 4), val_list))
colnames(have) <- c("id", "values")
have <- have %>% arrange(id)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
   id   values
1  1001      2
2  1001      2
3  1001      2
4  1001      3
5  1002      2
6  1002      3
7  1002      2
8  1002      2
9  1003      1
10 1003      3
11 1003      1
12 1003      2
```

What I want:

```
want <- data.frame(cbind(have[1:4, 2], 
                     have[5:8, 2],
                     have[9:12, 2]))
colnames(want) <- id
```

Output of want:

```
    1001 1002 1003
  1    2    2    1
  2    2    3    3
  3    2    2    1
  4    3    2    2
```

My original dataset has >1000 variables "id" and >50 variables "value". 
I want to chunk/ slice the dataset get a new data.frame where each "id" variable will represent one column listing its "value" variable content.

It is possible to solve it via a loop, but I want to have the vectorized solution. 
If possible with base R as "one-liner", but other solutions also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a unique row value for each `id` and use `pivot_wider`.

```
have %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = values) %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  `1001` `1002` `1003`
#   <int>  <int>  <int>
#1      1      3      1
#2      3      2      3
#3      2      2      3
#4      2      2      3
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(have), rowid(id)~id, value.var = 'values')
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L), values = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```